# variadic template to call a function

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I am trying to write a teamplate function that looks like this:

```
template<T FuncPtr, Params...>
void CallFunction(Params...)
{
    FuncPtr(Params...);
}
```

example usage:

```
typedef void (__stdcall* Test_t)(int a1, bool a2, char* a3);
Test_t fn = ....; //pointer obtained somehow

CallFunction<fn>(10, true, "Hello");
```

Is something like that possible? I dont know how to work with the parameter pack to have it unpacked so each member of the pack servers as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a minor rewrite into something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Fun, class... Args>
void CallFunction(Fun fun, Args&&... args)
{
    fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

void fn(int a1, bool a2, char const* a3)
{
    std::cout << a1 << a2 << a3;    
}

int main() 
{
    CallFunction(fn, 10, true, "Hello");
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcd5ee0528a3373f). I think you can deduce from this the proper `...` syntax (after `class...` in the paramter list, but after `arg...` for unpacking arguments at the call site.

The `std::forward` is to distinguish between lvalues and rvalues. It's also better in general to use argument deduction by passing the function pointer (or callable object in general) as a regular function argument, rather than as an explicit template argument.

Comment: thx bro this is working nicely. im new to this variadic template stuff and never seen forward before. you learn something new everyday :)